# System Notification binding for Ruby in Mountain Lion

Tags: ruby, osx-mountain-lion, growl

I don't want to use growl notifications from Ruby. I want to make use of Native System Notifications of Mountain Lion.

Do we have any gem that does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was looking forward to something like [rspec-nc](https://github.com/twe4ked/rspec-nc)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [terminal-notifier](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier/tree/master/Ruby#usage) of course it just wrapper around the [terminal-notifier command-line tool](https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier)